# Facebook plugin for PhoneGap "secure network request failed" issue

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I have installed Facebook Plugin for PhoneGap.
https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Facebook

I have built the application using "$phonegap build ios --device".

But problem is that after running the app on iPad my application gets stuck, and in the logs I get these warning messages:

```
[295:38227] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
[295:38188] FBSDKLog: WARNING: FBSDK secure network request failed. Please verify you have configured your app for Application Transport Security compatibility described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9
```

So as per the link "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9" I did few changes in the plist file, but still I am getting the same error in the logs.

**Problems that I am facing:**

1. How to find Facebook SDK version this plugin is using
2. When I call login API of the Plugin then it opens Safari browser and opens "facebook.com", how should force plugin to open Facebook native iOS app for user login request.
3. How to fix error that I am getting in the logs

Comment: 2. Not possible; Facebook had to do it this way due to changes Apple made in iOS. 3. describe what settings you made, instead of saying you “made a few changes”, which means everything and nothing at the same time.

Comment: Actually I don't know SDK version of Facebook that plugin is using so I did only, point number two "2. Whitelist Facebook Apps". I did this change in plist file of my app. nothing else I did from this link.